# Error in python int object is not subscriptable,

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I was writing a simple code for a leetcode question [Plus one](https://leetcode.com/problems/plus-one) using reccursion.

The question reads:

> Given a non-empty array of digits representing a non-negative integer,
>   plus one to the integer.
>
> The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the
>   head of the list, and each element in the array contain a single
>   digit.
>
> You may assume the integer does not contain any leading zero, except
>   the number 0 itself.

I am getting an error in line 7 when input is `[9, 9]`.

My code goes like this:

```
class Solution:
    def plusOne(self, digits: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        i=-1
        j=-len(digits)
        k=0
        def recur(i,digits):
            if digits[0]==0:
                return [1]
            if i==j:
                if digits[i]==9:
                    digits[i]=0
                    digits.insert(0,1)
                    return digits
                else:
                    digits[i]=digits[i]+1
                    return digits
            if digits[i]==9:
                digits[i]=0
                return recur(digits,i-1)
            digits[i]=digits[i]+1
            return digits
        return recur(i,digits)
```

Comment: You have the arguments reversed in your call to `recur`: `return recur(digits,i-1)` should be `return recur(i-1, digits)`.

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function recursively add one to all but the last digit if the last digit is 9, and append `0` to it; otherwise simply add one to the last digit. If the input is empty, return a single digit `1` so that it can handle carrying to a new digit:

```
def plusOne(digits):
    if not digits:
        return [1]
    if digits[-1] < 9:
        return digits[:-1] + [digits[-1] + 1]
    return plusOne(digits[:-1]) + [0]
```

so that:

```
print(plusOne([1, 2, 3]))
print(plusOne([2, 9, 9]))
print(plusOne([9, 9, 9]))
```

returns:

```
[1, 2, 4]
[3, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```